# Is it safe to transform dates back and forth using UTC in order to ignore DST but still using a valid locale for the current user?

Tags: c++, date, utc, date-conversion

I have a date (no time, assuming time 00:00:00) that I convert between a `time_t` and a `struct tm`.

I get a date in the simple YYYYMMDD format and convert that to a `struct tm`:

```
struct tm my_tm;
memset(&my_tm, 0, sizeof(my_tm));
my_tm.tm_year = str.mid(0, 4).toInt() - 1900;
my_tm.tm_mon = str.mid(4, 2).toInt() - 1;
my_tm.tm_mday = str.mid(6, 2).toInt();
```

- *P.S.: for those wondering I have a `QString` (Qt) hence the `mid()` and `toInt()` members used.*

Then I convert that date to a `time_t` using `mktime()`:

```
time_t my_time(mktime(&my_tm));
```

At that point the date changes to the day before (more precisely, -1h) if the date is March 6, 2016 ("20160306" becomes 2016/03/05 in the `struct tm`). This is because of DST (the tm_isdst is set accordingly).

I have another version of `mktime()` called [`mkgmtime()`](https://sourceforge.net/p/snapcpp/code/ci/master/tree/snapwebsites/lib/mkgmtime.c) and that works as expected: I get the same date since DST is ignored by that function:

```
time_t my_time(mkgmtime(&my_tm));
```

I can then convert the date back to a `struct tm` using the `gmtime_r()` function. This way, again, I get the same date:

```
struct tm other_tm;
gmtime_r(&my_time, &other_tm);
```

However, at some point I want to display the date in a standard format as defined by the end user's locale. For that I use the ICU library. In the following, I force `f_current_timezone` variable to UTC before calling `format_date()`, then the date comes out as **Mar 6, 2016** (if I keep the user timezone, I may instead get *Mar 5, 2016*.)

```
QString locale::format_date(time_t d)
{
    QUnicodeString const timezone_id(f_current_timezone);
    LocalPointer<TimeZone> tz(TimeZone::createTimeZone(timezone_id));
    Locale const l(f_current_locale.toUtf8().data());
    LocalPointer<DateFormat> dt(DateFormat::createDateInstance(DateFormat::kDefault, l));
    dt->setTimeZone(*tz);
    UDate const udate(d * 1000LL);
    QUnicodeString u;
    dt->format(udate, u);
    return u;
}
```

Is it safe (Does it make sense to you) to use "UTC" as the timezone to get the correct result from `format_date()`?

Answer (score 0):

Before using `mktime()`, set tm_hour to 12 (12pm). If all you care about is formatting the date portion using the application's locate, using noon for `mktime()` will be sufficient, for that purpose.

Comment: I thought of that, but what if your timezone is +12 or -12 hours? Wouldn't that be affected?

Comment: mktime uses the local timezone. It will attempt to use whatever noon in the local timezone is.